# Printing key from dictionary that previous function returns

Tags: python

I came across this problem. Not sure how to continue.

My dictionary:

```
DICT = {
    "inside": "It's obviously inside",
    "outside": "It went outside"
}
```

I have a function that returns a dictionary key. Then I have a printing function that should print the value connected to that function.

If my previous function's return line is `return "inside"`, I tried this:

```
def print_location(key):
    print(DICT[key])
```

This seems not to be working. Somehow I might need to connect the variable 'key' to the returned key but this is where I get stuck. How could I do this?

Comment: Can you post the error that you're getting?

Comment: You want to print the key or the value for that key?

Comment: What is the problem? I have checked your function and it works correctly.

Comment: what is not working add some details about your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine; the following works as expected:

```py
DICT = {
    "inside": "It's obviously inside",
    "outside": "It went outside"
}

def get_key():
    return 'inside'

def print_location(key):
    print(DICT[key])

# run the code
the_key = get_key()
print_location(the_key)  # prints "It's obviously inside"
```

Comment: may be he was defining the dictionary below function definition and not passing it in the print_location() as a parameter. your method is correct.

Comment: or perhaps not passing `the_key` into `print_location` at all

Comment: yeah true. i did the edit then saw your comment.

Comment: This works, brilliant! Thanks!